# Why does Buffer.from('\x80', 'utf8') return <Buffer c2 80>

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why does this happen

```
> Buffer.from('\x79', 'utf8')
<Buffer 79>
> Buffer.from('\x80', 'utf8')
<Buffer c2 80>
```

and how do I get `Buffer` to behave how I expect and return a `<Buffer 80>` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `0x80` or `1000 0000` in binary or 128 in decimal is not a valid code point in UTF-8 because it is outside of ASCII (which is 7 bits, so all ASCII code points have the first bit set to `0`). To convert strings to `Buffer`s without interpreting them as UTF-8, you can use the `'ascii'` encoding instead:

```
> Buffer.from('\x79', 'ascii')
<Buffer 79>
> Buffer.from('\x80', 'ascii')
<Buffer 80>

> Buffer.from('', 'ascii')
<Buffer 3d bb>
> Buffer.from('', 'utf8')
<Buffer f0 9f 92 bb>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even tho [@Boris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66643999/5625547)'s answer does explain the behaviour, I just wanted to point out that:

As from the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings):

- The `'ascii'` encoding is considered a **legacy character encoding**

As another solution, using the `latin1` encoding, should give the desired result:

> - 'latin1': Latin-1 stands for [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1).
>
>   This character encoding only supports the Unicode characters from U+0000 to U+00FF. Each character is encoded using a single byte. Characters that do not fit into that range are truncated and will be mapped to characters in that range.

```
const a = Buffer.from('\x80', 'utf8');
const b = Buffer.from('\x80', 'latin1')
console.log(a, b);
// <Buffer c2 80> <Buffer 80>
```

<sup>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/OT@vuEQhUcFWwak0LS21SC@tKD9XQz2mwsJAXUdBvbQkzUJd05oLoiwJl7KcxJLMPEN1TbC6/JxUvZz8dI1EHYUkTev//wE)</sup>

Comment: Every encoding that isn't UTF8 is a legacy encoding in my book.